# Handling DropDown using Protractor

Tags: webdriver, javascript, protractor

I am facing issues with handling a trivial scenario during automation. I need to select a specific option using Protractor. I am passing the index of the option that I want to select, and then clicking on that to select it. However, my `click()` method errors out stating the `click()` method is undefined on that index.

Here is what I am trying to do - in my `selectElements.js` file, the dropdown method is defined as

```
const selectElement={}

selectElement.selectElementDropdown =function(element,index,milliseconds){
 console.log("Selecting element by drop down","OK");

 element.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(options){

     options[2].click(); 
//here index 2 is hardcoded, which can be changed to options[index]
 });

 if(typeof milliseconds!=='undefined'){
     browser.sleep(milliseconds);
 }

}

module.exports =selectElement;
```

I am using a POM structure, so the dropdown method is in a separate `.js` file. I am calling this in my page file:

```
const methodDropDown = require('../BasePage/selectElements.js');

var signUpBankDetails = function(){

this.bankName = element.all(by.css('.form-group')).get(7).element(by.xpath("//label[text()='Select Bank Name']"));
//the selector is clicked to open the drop down

console.log("Start of this block =========>");

this.selectDropDownMethod = function(){
    console.log("Drop Down method start ==========>");
    this.bankName.click();
    browser.sleep(1000);
    methodDropDown.selectElementDropdown(this.bankName,0,1000);

};
```

I am getting the error which says:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

The `this.bankName.click()` block is working fine because, I can see that the element is clicked and the drop down appears, however the selection seems to be erroring out. I have also attached the HTML snippet of code below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging the inner text of `this.bankName`? It may not be referring to the element you think it is - as I read the HTML here, clicking anything in the grouping will cause the dropdown to display options, but the object handle may not be the `<select>...</select>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can use [`.get()` method of the `ElementArrayFinder`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) - no need to resolve a promise explicitly:

```
var desiredOption = element.all(by.tagName('option')).get(2);
```

Then, assuming you are clicking the right "button" to open up the options, you can *wait for the option to become visible*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(desiredOption), 5000);
desiredOption.click();
```

There is also this [nice wrapper around `Select` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28736559/771848), which, aside from other things, will allow you to select an option by text or value (would be better than hardcoding an index of an option).

Answer (score 0):

Keep this method  in `selectElements.js`:

```
exports.SelectValueFromDropDown = function selectDropdownByNumber(element, index) {
    element.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(options) {
        options[index].click();
    });      
}
```

Call this method from other class:

```
var commonFunction = require('path of selectElements.js');
commonFunction.SelectValueFromDropDown(Title, 3);
```

Comment: You don't need to resolve the array of elements promise in order to get one by index - there is the built-in `.get()` method - no need to overcomplicate.